# Validating header names for an SQL column list

Tags: c#, regex

I am currently trying to make a user friendly input for people to input SQL headers for a CSV that is created using a temporary table, however I am having issues with validating and changing the names to SQL friendly column headers.

An example input would be as follows:

**Name, Ag-e, Gender, Birth Place, Rac+e**

Please keep in mind that the input could be ANY word, these are simply an example.
My ideal final output would for the SQL column headers

**name age gender birth_place race**

however I am having issues checking for invalid characters (which I haven't actually got around to yet.) but my primary issue I am currently having is checking for spaces between words that SHOULD have a space and other spaces at the start of words.

My current output is coming out as(please note that the invalid characters are for testing later.):

**Name  Ag-e  Gender  Birth Place  Rac+e**

Please note that there are double spaces between every one apart from Birth Place which has a single space as it should.

The code I am currently using to achieve this (or not achieve as you can clearly see) is:

```
            columnNamesList = new List<string>(columnNames.Split(splitChar));
        columnNamesList[0] = columnNamesList[0].Trim();
        columnNamesList[columnNamesList.Count - 1] = columnNamesList[columnNamesList.Count - 1].TrimEnd();
        List<string> removalList = new List<string>();

        foreach (string i in columnNamesList)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(i))
            {
                removalList.Add(i);
            }
        }

        if (removalList.Count < 0)
        {
            foreach (string i in removalList)
            {
                columnNamesList.Remove(i);
            }
        }


        for (int i = 0; i < columnNamesList.Count; i++)
        {
            string s = string.Empty;
            string str = columnNamesList[i];

            if (Regex.IsMatch(str, @"\w\s\w+", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
            {
                foreach (char c in str)
                {
                    if (Char.IsLetterOrDigit(c) || c == ' ' || c == ',')
                        s += c;
                    s = s.Replace(' ', '_');
                    columnNamesList[i] = s;
                }
            }
        }

        string[] columnArray = columnNamesList.ToArray<string>();
        columnNames = String.Join(" ", columnArray);
```

Comment: Can't you just wrap all column names in '[' and ']' i.e. `[Birth Place]`

Comment: I could for the actual query to stop issues with keywords, however I don't think having a space in a column name is acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

I thought you said that the input is like the first string, comma separated.
Does this not work? All you have to do is remove the unwanted characters (against a blacklist)

```
        var input = "Name, Ag-e, Gender, Birth Place, Rac+e";
        var splitInput = input.Split(',')
            .Select(i => 
                i.Trim()
                .ToLower()  
                .Replace(' ','_'));
        var output = string.Join(" ", splitInput.ToArray());
```

Comment: I'm afraid not, as I need to find some form of validation on the spaces.